# Где найти список свойств, которые мы можем прописать в Intellij IDEA vm options при запуске Spring Boot?

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, jvm, запуск

Скачал **Spring Boot** проект, а там в настройках (**run/debug configuration** -> **VM options**), есть такие переменные как:

```
-Dspring.config.additional
-DkeyStoreConfig
-Dlogging.config
-DserviceLog
-DexternalResources
```

Интуитивно, я конечно понимаю, что они все значат, но хотелось бы найти документацию, по каждому конкретному свойству, желательно с примером.

**Вопрос:** дайте пожалуйста ссылочку на документацию по этим свойствам (которые прописываются в VM Options Intellij IDEA) и по всем другим (если возможно) чтобы я знал, какие ещё свойства можно прописать в VM Options. Потому что у меня, что-то не гуглится.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties

Comment: Через `-D` задаются не VM options, а System Properties, которые использует запущенная программа. VM options это https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html